# Why are points from this matrix geometric sequence co-planar?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, matrices, markov-chains

Let 
$
   M=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{ccc}
   a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} & a_{1,3} \\
   a_{2,1} & a_{2,2} & a_{2,3} \\
   a_{3,1} & a_{3,2} & a_{3,3} \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$,
such that $a_{1,n} + a_{2,n} + a_{3,n} = 1.$

As an example, $M$ could equal 
$
  \left[ {\begin{array}{ccc}
   .3 & .1 & .8 \\
   .5 & .4 & .1 \\
   .2 & .5 & .1 \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$.

Let 
$ v=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{c}
   x \\
   y \\
   z \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$,
where $x$, $y$, and $z$ are all positive.

The geometric sequence $v, Mv, M^2v...$ define a series of vectors. Adding those vectors to the origin gives us a series of points. Show that these points are co-planar.

I've done some reading on this and some people have mentioned Eigenvectors, etc. I am currently in precalc and so I'd rather have nothing more advanced than calculus be used. I also *think* this is a Markov chain so I'm also adding that to the tags, feel free to remove it if you disagree.

Comment: The first column of $M$ doesn't add to 1.

Comment: uhh oops... I'll fix that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given some thought, I've realized the answer is simple. Let $W = x + y + z$. Because this is a Markov chain, for all $M^nv$, $x_{M^nv}+y_{M^nv}+z_{M^nv} = W$. The equation this line fits is $x + y + z = W$. Thanks for the help everyone. I'm amazed I did not see this last night.

Comment: Positivity is irrelevant. Notice that you never used the assumption of positivity. The statement is true without it.